# Oninput data matches regexp pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I validate vehicle VIN by using this expression:

```
/^X7L[A-Z0-9]{14}$/g
```

But I'd like to do validation every time user typing in input field: user won't get error, until VIN is matches pattern. Could you please help me with regular expression for it?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear: are you using it in a JavaScript `RegExp#test()` method? Remove `g`. Or, if you want to ensure the match result is reversed, use `if (!/pattern/.test(s))`...

Comment: The user _won't_ get an error until the input matches, or he _will_ get an error until a match is reached?

Comment: Using javascript test()

Comment: User won't get an error